# Forks and Pointers in C

Tags: c, unix, pointers, process, fork

Can someone help me understand how the system handles variables that are set before a process makes a `fork()` call. Below is a small test program I wrote to try understanding what is going on behind the scenes.

I understand that the current state of a process is "cloned", variables included,  at the time of the forking. My thought was, that if I malloc'd a 2D array before calling fork, I would need to free the array both in the parent and the child processes.

As you can see from the results below the sample code, the two values act as if they are totally separate from each other, yet they have the exact same address space. I expected that my final result for tmp would be `-4` no matter which process completed first.

I am newer to C and Linux, so could someone explain how this is possible? Perhaps the variable tmp becomes a pointer to a pointer which is distinct in each process? Thanks so much.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int tmp = 1;
    pid_t forkReturn= fork();

    if(!forkReturn) {

        /*child*/
        tmp=tmp+5;
        printf("Value for child %d\n",tmp);
        printf("Address for child %p\n",&tmp);
    }

    else if(forkReturn > 0){

        /*parent*/
        tmp=tmp-10;
        printf("Value for parent %d\n",tmp);
        printf("Address for parent %p\n",&tmp);
    }

    else {

        /*Error calling fork*/
        printf("Error calling fork);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

RESULTS of standard out:

```
Value for child 6
Address for child 0xbfb478d8
Value for parent -9
Address for parent 0xbfb478d8
```

Comment: there is a misconception about the returned value from `fork()`.   `fork()` has three possible returns: 1) >0 means parent 2) =0 means child 3) <0 means an error occurred. The statement: `if( child )` is not correct.  if that statement evaluates to true, then either it is parent or fork() failed  To check for child use: `if( !child)`  Which means the variable name is a poor choice.  Please read/understand the man page for `fork()`

Comment: here is an excerpt from the man page for `fork()`: "On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and
       0  is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the parent,
       no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately."

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my actual code I have specified as forkReturn, but I was being lazy with this example code. I'll edit for clarification though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It did indeed copy the entire address space, and changing memory in the child process does not affect the parent. The key to understanding this is to remember that a pointer can only point to something in your own process, and the copy happens at a lower level.

However, you should not call malloc() or free() at all in the child of fork. This can deadlock (another thread was in malloc() when you called fork()). The only functions safe to call in the child are the ones also listed as safe for signal handlers. I used to be able to claim this was true only if you wrote multithreaded code; however Apple was kind enough to spawn a background thread in the standard library, so the deadlock is real all the time. The child of fork should never be allowed to drop out of the if block. Call _exit to make sure it doesn't.

Comment: To make sure I understand, the copied address space means that both the child and parent will have the same address for the variable, but somewhere lower the actual value is stored in separate memory sectors. So an address references different physical sectors depending on the process when a `fork()` is called.

How does this affect freeing up that memory if it is only being called from the parent?

Comment: There are no threads (or there's only the main thread) in this code; the caveat about threads and fork is complicating things unnecessarily.

Comment: @GullySquad02: after the fork, the parent and the child have almost identical memory layouts in the virtual memory, but their variables point to their own copies in physical memory. You only work with virtual addresses, so they look the same in each program. The main differences between the forked child and the parent are the PID and PPID values and the return value from `fork()`. There are other differences — the child has a single thread even if the parent was multi-threaded, for example — full details at POSIX [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html).

Comment: OP,  lets remember that every process runs in its' own `virtual` address space.and the `loader` (unless told specifically otherwise) loads each process in the same address space in a new virtual address space.   I.E. each process thinks it has the same address space of 0x0 through 0xFFFFFFFF (32 bit architecture)  When the new process is first started, it has the same exact data in the same memory page,  But if the child write anything to that data, then a new memory page is allocated and mapped in the child to the same virtual address and everything is copied (called: `copy on write`)

Comment: Thanks you Jonathan and @user3629249. This is **much** clearer to me now. Hope it helps others as well.